# Create New Address Type Just Like Shipping & Billing

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I would like to create an address entity for order just like billing and shipping, let us call it return address but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Comment: You can check this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57674/custom-module-to-add-a-3rd-customer-address-type
Hope this help for what you need.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply but this answer is fot magento 1.9.1.0 and I'm actually looking this for magento 2 and specially for magento 2.3